# Issues with using ualarm

Tags: c, unix, signals, alarm

In my code, i need to call sigalrm after 2 seconds. However, when i use             `ualarm(2000000, 0 )` it doesn't work. using `ualarm` less than 1 second works. Whereas `alarm(2)` works. Is there a reason why `ualarm` should be used at times over `alarm`? Is there any way to get `ualarm` to work for over 1 second?

Comment: Please show a [mcve]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ualarm()` is obsolete, and in fact has been removed from POSIX.  Do not use it.

If you insist on using it anyway, the Linux manual page for it notes this:

> The type useconds_t is an unsigned integer type capable of holding integers in the range [0,1000000].

, which I guess is a reference to the one-time POSIX specification.  What you should take from that is that POSIX `ualarm()` was never guaranteed to be able to handle a first argument larger than 1000000.  It's unclear whether any implementations ever did handle larger values, but the fact that POSIX specified it as it did suggests that at least some implementations did not.

> Is there any way to get ualarm to work for over 1 second?

Since there is not (any longer) any standard for `ualarm()`, the answer is necessarily implementation-dependent.  Based on what you presented, I'm inclined to think that with your implementation, the answer is "no".

Comment: Just for some extra knowledge, is alarm the replacement of ualarm?

Comment: @duckvader, `alarm()` does not have the same resolution as `ualarm()`, but it's a fine alternative if that's sufficient.  In BSD, were it originated, `ualarm()` was a wrapper around `getitimer()` / `setitimer()`.  Those are now also obsolete (though maybe not yet removed).  The recommended replacement is POSIX timers, accessed via `timer_gettime()` / `timer_settime()`.